# drupal tablesort_sql sort by default but don't show in header

Tags: drupal, themes, tablesorter

I want to create a simple table and make it available for user to sort on the headers.
Using the tablesort_sql() function and sending the $header into theme() this can be done easy and nice.

But i want to sort by default on a field that is not visible to the users.
as example:
I want the content to be sorted by the created date, but i dont want to show that to the users

So here is what I've got:

`function vacancies_overview() {
    GLOBAL $user;`

```
$header = array(
        array('field' => 'created', 'sort' => 'desc'),
        array('data' => t('title'), 'field' => 'title'),
);


$sql = "SELECT n.nid, n.title FROM {node} n WHERE n.type = 'mycontenttype' AND n.status = 1 AND n.uid = %d" . tablesort_sql($header);


$result = pager_query($sql, 30, 0, NULL, $user->uid);
while ($data = db_fetch_object($result)) {
    $rows[] = array(
        _mycontent_format_title_link($data->title, $data->nid),
    );
}

$output = theme('table', $header, $rows);
$output .= theme('pager', NULL, 30, 0);

return $output;
```

}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A quick solution would be to do something like this:

```
$header = array(
    array('field' => 'created', 'sort' => 'desc'),
    array('data' => t('title'), 'field' => 'title'),
);

$header_sort = $header;
$header_sort[] = array(...); // Add the default sort.
```

Then you can use `header_sort` for the sql and `$header` for the theming of the table.

Comment: I can see this will work :) how stupid of me not to think of this :P
Thnx for pointing this out!